# GARCH model why we take assumption that returns arei.i.d. random variable?

Tags: random-variables

In GARCH model why we take assumption that returns are i.i.d.?how can we explain it to a layman?

Comment: I think this question probably belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree in principle but similar has already been asked, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/466927/31642 so migration will probably not appreciated by the receiving site.

Comment: I suggest we let the question stand, and suggest it be reworded. It sounds like the OP is asking why GARCH assumes i.i.d returns rather than asking for a layman's explanation of i.i.d.